# The white X appears in the grey box on all browsers I have but Safari on iPad. Did I make a mistake or Safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad, safari

On Safari on Ipad the white X appears on the right hand part of the black. This is the only Safari I have though so unsure if iPad issue or Safari issue or my issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/juvpxa8q/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="piece-info-container">
            <div id="piece-info">
                <div id="piece-info-top">
                    <div class="piece-info-row">
                        <i id="close-piece-info" class="fa fa-window-close unselectable" aria-hidden="true">X</i>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what is the issue? You want it to appear on the left hand side?

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky X inside the grey box on all browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Add `position: relative` to `#piece-info-container`.

It has to do with the resetting of the children's positions.

---

To be honest, it'd be best to rethink your CSS from the ground up because `position:absolute` inside of a `sticky` inside of a `fixed` is a recipe for trouble.

It's quite common to be wanting to position icons in the top right corner... A good place to start could be taking a look at [Bootstrap's modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modal-components). Look at the `.modal-header` separation and using `float` to position the `x` it to the right.

Comment: Just tested this on Chrome: white X is in the upper right corner of the grey part, adding `position: relative` to `#piece-info-container` did not break that. I agree that this is caused by the `position: absolute` having trouble orientating itself on the nearest `position: relative` element.

Comment: Chrome was okay -- this is a safari fix.

Comment: Sry for the useless comment, I got confused about what was the intended and actual behavior.